# Get Source Code from debug installed App

Tags: android, reverse-engineering

I have got an App installed on my phone (not rooted), this App was in Development at the time and installed in Debug mode.

I would like to know how to get the Java Code of this App, since it's in Debug mode.
I'm guessing some ind of reverse engineering but I'm not expert on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the APK (the application file) to do that. Since you are not rooted, you will not be able to get the APK.

With the APK, you can use tools like: www.decompileandroid.com/